# Can I create unordered_map for size of integer upto 10^9?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, c++14, unordered-map

I'm solving a problem where I need to use hashing, I just want to store integers in a container and check whether a particular integer is there in the container or not?

here's a piece of my code-

```
// Creating an unordered map-
unordered_map<long long int, long long int> example;

// increasing the counter of particular element-
example[element]++;

// checking wheather count of another element is zero or not, basically it is there or not
if(example[another_element]){
    // do something;
}
```

I just want to know will it gonna work for integer size of 10^9 or not? Can anyone please help.

Comment: 10^9 < 2^32 so you don't need long long. But the real issue is how many numbers you're expecting to store: is this fairly sparse, i.e. a few thousand in a large range, or is it many more than that?

Comment: If you just want to know if an element is in the container or not then use `std::unordered_set` instead. Use `std::unordered_map` only if the actual number of times the element occurs matters.

Comment: Beware, operator[] is inserting elements! consider using `find`, or `count` (or even `contains` for C++20)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks for the help man, I actually switched to set looking at the options ;)

Comment: @OneLyner No it didn't. I cross-checked the code. I was just incrementing the count of element.

Comment: @PrateekGautam Check again: "performing an insertion if such key does not already exist" see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I create unordered_map for size of integer upto 10^9?

Yes. Both `long long` and `long` are guaranteed to be able to represent all integers up to 10<sup>9</sup>. Unordered map has no effect on that, as per documentation.

> just want to store integers in a container and check whether a particular integer is there in the container or not?

Sounds like you want a set rather than a map.

---

Also, don't do this:

> ```
> if(example[another_element])
> ```

to check whether the map contains an element. This unnecessarily inserts an element into the map if it didn't exist yet.

Comment: I can also use unordered_set. But won't it take O(N) time to check if element is there or not, because I think it linearly searches for an element in a set.

Comment: @PrateekGautam Unordered set lookup is O(1) in average case. Worst case is O(N) though (in case you have a bad hash function). Worst case of ordered set lookup is  O(log N). These guarantees are the same for the map containers.

Comment: @eeronika please add the operator[] is in fact inserting element (with count equal to 0). If you want to check a lot of values not in the set, this would lead to memory issues.

Comment: @OneLyner Added, although that mistake cannot be repeated with set which doesn't have the subscript operator.

Comment: @eerorika Okay I'm now using the set, but in my previous case how to check if count of an element is 0 or not in map without using [] operator? Should I use find() method?

Comment: @PrateekGautam you can use find - or you can use contains if you know that you won't add zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bitset, size 2^27 bytes (128mb). Bit 1 in the appropriate index will define "element within set", and bit 0 will be "element not in set".
Such set can be easy written as class like:

```
class bitset1G {
  public:
  bitset1G() { bzero(_data, sizeof(_data)); }
  void set(uint32_t x) { _data[x >> 5] |= (1 << (x & 0x1f)); }
  void clr(uint32_t x) { _data[x >> 5] &= ~(1 << (x & 0x1f)); }
  bool tst(uint32_t x) { return _data[x >> 5] & (1 << (x & 0x1f)); }
  private:
  int32_t _data[1 << 25]; // 1G bits
};
```